# sticker picker and image picker in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm making an android chat app using kotlin, how can i implement sticker and image picker in keyboard with sticker available in the app and show and choose image like Messager App. it look like this

[sticker picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMEvt.png) and [image picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJe4o.png)